# Orthonormality Properties of the Dual Basis in $\mathbb{C}^N$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

## 1 Context

I'm working on an undergraduate textbook on Harmonic Analysis. The notational buildup for a problem I'm having is long but fairly straightforward and standard:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

## 2 Problem

> [image]

**Attempt:**

1. First note that

   $$
   v_k = a_0 v_1 + \ldots + a_k v_k + \ldots + a_N v_N = 0 v_1 + \ldots + 1 v_k + \ldots + 0 v_N
   $$

   so that $a_j = 0$ if $k \ne j$ and $a_j = 1$ if $k = j$.
2. But

   $$
   \langle v_k, w_j \rangle = a_j
   $$

   which from (1) shows that

$$
\langle v_k, w_j \rangle = \delta_{j,k}
$$

I'm skeptical that this argument is right though since it doesn't depend on $w_j$. Moreover, how does one show that

$$
\sum_{j=1}^N \langle v, w_j \rangle v_j = \sum_{j=1}^N \langle v, v_j \rangle w_j?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of this exercise is already given by your post, as the coordinate of each $v_k$ under the basis $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}\subset \mathbb C^N$ is exactly $[\delta_{kl}]_{l=1}^N$.

For the remnant part of this exercise, I would like to use the notion of *dual space* and *dual basis* in linear algebra, but you can avoid these notions and prove the exercise in the same manner with no difficulty. Let us denote 
$$
v^j:=\langle -,w_j\rangle,\ w^j:=\langle -,v_j\rangle.
$$
It is clear that $w^j$ and $v^j$ so defined are linear functionals over $\mathbb C^N$, i.e., elements of the dual space $(\mathbb C^N)^*$. The orthonormality proved in this exercise indicates that $\{v^j\}$ and $\{w^j\}$ are exactly the *dual bases* of resp. $\{v_j\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ in $(\mathbb C^N)^*$. Now for each $v\in \mathbb C^N$, one has
$$
v=\sum_{j=1}^Na_jv_j=\sum_{j=1}^Nb_jw_j
$$
for some $a_j,b_j\in\mathbb C$ (since $\{v_j\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are both bases of $\mathbb C^N$), and then with $v$ acted by resp. $v^j$ and $w^j$, it can be seen that
$$
a_j=v^j(v)=\langle v,w_j\rangle,b_j=w^j(v)=\langle v,v_j\rangle.
$$
Thus it follows that
$$
v=\sum_{j=1}^N\langle v,w_j\rangle v_j=\sum_{j=1}^N\langle v,v_j\rangle w_j.
$$

Comment: Just to be clear: by your first comment do you mean that I was right in my attempt to solve the first part of this problem?

Comment: @user1770201 Yes, you are right~

Comment: How does one know that $b_j = \langle v, v_j \rangle$? The textbook only justifies that $a_j = \langle v, w_j \rangle$, right?

Comment: Another issue: how does one know that $\{w_j\}$ is actually a basis of $\mathbb{C}^N$?

Comment: @user1770201 (Sorry I made a typo in the previous version of this comment and I deleted it). Note that $$\langle v,v_j\rangle=w^j(v)=\sum_{i=1}^Nb_iw^j(w_i)=\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i\delta_{ji}=b_j.$$ For the second issue, since $w_j(j=1,\cdots,N)$ are rows of an invertible matrix $\overline{B^{-1}}$, they are linearly independent. Thus $\{w_j\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb C^N$.